# Unable to access Remote Desktop on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, authentication, remote-desktop, azure-cloud-services

I have a newly created Azure Cloud Service. A sample project has been deployed and everything is working fine.

I now need remote desktop access to the service. After enabling Remote Desktop connections through the Azure Portal, downloading and running the generated .rdp file in windows I get the error:

```
An authentication has occured (Code: 0x80004005)
```

From windows Remote Desktop.

Signing information has been checked and double checked, same result on multiple computers.

So, steps taken:

- Created Cloud service with roles
- Enabled Remote Desktop through the Azure portal
- Downloaded and run .rdp file

Has anyone else experienced this and/or have any solutions?

Comment: I can't repro this issue on my side. Do you have a try to use another user or password and make the account is not expired? (Change the user and password from the Azure portal).

Comment: I have a very similar problem atm. @TomSun-MSFT Could you maybe submit an answer with the steps you've taken to successfully log in?

Comment: Please refer to Nikolaj Langberg Gustafsson's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution.

When enabling remote desktop in the Azure portal, I had chosen a username that was not my email.

If I use my Azure account email as username, everything works perfectly.

After testing, in fact any email will do.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem and this answer made me realize, that I'm probably using the wrong domain for the user. So you can solve this problem also by entering the user name as `AZURE\myusername`.